# Angular component output in property

Tags: angular, vis.js

I have the following component implementing the interface DataItem.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'timeline-box',
    templateUrl: './timeline-box.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./timeline-box.component.css']
})
export class TimelineBoxComponent implements OnInit, DataItem {
    id: IdType;
    content: string;
    start: DateType;
    end: DateType;

    constructor( elem: TimelineElement  ) {
        this.id = elem.id;
        this.content = '<p>' + elem.title + '</p>';
        this.start = new Date(elem.start);
        this.end = new Date(elem.end);
    }

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

My problem is the property "content", which is used by the third-part component to print my element. I want to remove the html from the constructor and use in some way the template of the component.

So I think I need to "redirect" the output of the component in the variable content in some way. How can I do it? There is a better way?

The interface is part of an external module (ng-vis) and I cant change it.

**UPDATE**

The component at the moment is used as a normal class, maybe it shouldn't be a component at all.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'timeline',
    templateUrl: './timeline.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./timeline.component.css']
})
export class TimelineComponent implements OnInit {
    items: VisTimelineItems;
    timeline: Timeline;

    constructor(private element: ElementRef, private elementService: TimelineElementService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.items = new VisTimelineItems(  );

        this.elementService.getElements(1507500000).then( this.extractData.bind(this) );

        this.timeline = new Timeline(this.element.nativeElement, this.items);
    }

    extractData( array: TimelineElement[] ) {
        for (var obj of array) {
            this.items.add(new TimelineBoxComponent(obj));
        }

        this.timeline.redraw();
    }
}
```

As you can see the TimelineBoxComponent is used as a Datasource of the module, it sound really wrong now that I write it :) But I have no idea how can I implement a normal class with an html template .

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: The component's template? It's currently not used so its empty.

Comment: `./timeline-box.component.html` is empty? How are you implementing this component? Typically the constructor parameters of a component are for Dependency Injection only. If you are trying to pass parameters from a parent component to this component I would recommend input bindings (https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding)

Comment: Question updated with usage :)

Comment: You are correct, you do not need the @Component() decorator. (so also no ngOnInit method) According to the vis.js docs, the content field can either be plaintext or html. So whatever html you pass to content should be loaded as the label.

Comment: Oh I see, I dont really like HTML generation as string concatenation in the model but if there isnt another way so be it. Thank you.

Comment: The ng2-vis library is really just a wrapper library for vis.js. So for html generation, ng2-vis is at the mercy of however vis.js is implementing it.